# Does PGStrom calculate relational comparisons?

Tags: postgresql, performance, index

I prefer index calculation and comparison be executed on the GPU.

I have stumbled upon [PGStrom](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PGStrom).

It seems one could infer that it will calculate index comparisons, but the claim doesn't seem to be made explicitly, and I stopped assuming years ago.

As an example, would PGStrom calculate this where condition:

```
SELECT * FROM some_parent, some_child 
    WHERE some_parent.bigint_id = some_child.parent_bigint_id
```

Does PGStrom calculate relational comparisons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, pgstrom cannot do that. it only able to scan relations - it is not able to join.
what you an do is pack an operator into a GPU routine but = is not a good candidate for that.

Comment: absolutely. the join thing is not possible because things will only work on tables, which were actually loaded into the GPU. i cannot see the thing you requested happen any time soon to be honest (would be cool, however).